# How to determine the pole number or synchronous speed of an AC motor from its rated RPM?

Tags: motor, ac

Trying to to determine the pole number or synchronous speed of the following AC motor from its rated RPM. Here are the details:

http://www.vanbodegraven.nl/en/products/ac-motors/asea-mbg-200-m-60-6/

What is its synchronous speed(stator winding frequency) and pole number?

**A VFD is being used**

Comment: This question is closely related to http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/161956/calculate-rotor-slip-without-knowing-synchronous-speed/161965#161965 .

Comment: -1. The important fact that a VFD is in use was not mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a table that has been useful to me in the past: -

[image]

Please also note that the motor you have linked is a standard induction motor and won't run at synchronous speed. It's likely to be a 6 pole machine running at 50Hz that would produce a synchronous speed of 1000 RPM. However there are a few other options that could be close but, as 50Hz is a standard frequency I suggest it is a 6 pole machine.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be an Induction machine for the European market & a 3pole pair machine.

Justification?

1) referring to 380Δ connection, url is netherlands, dialcode is +31 => 50Hz AC

2) the RPM listed is 970rpm. the peak operating point of an induction machine is just below the equivalent electrical sync speed.  50Hz for a single pole machine equates to 3000rpm. 1000rpm would be the closest integer divisor

Comment: can I open chat with you

Comment: we measure more than 1000 rpm like 1160 rpm. How can it be possible?

Comment: sounds like you hooked it upto 60Hz. 60Hz 3pole pair would have an electrical SYNC speed of 1200rpm ==> around 1100 taking into account the induction machine & slip

Comment: no it is 50hz in europe

Comment: we use a vfd but vfd cannot increase motor speed more than its synchronous speed right?

Comment: I know it is 50Hz in Europe (sitting here waiting for UK results.) but it is the simplest explaination as to why you would get > 1000rpm. The other is the accuracy in your speed measurement

Comment: A VFD (Variable Frequency drive) can generated greater than 50Hz & it is probably set to generate 60Hz output

Comment: i dont understand this. rated frequency is 50hz which means rated sync speed must be 1000 rpm if it is 6 pole. so it means it is  applying more frequency. does that mean the stator voltage should be proportionally increased to keep v/f constant? i only know the stator currents and mechanical rpms. is current decrease must be proportional to mechanical rpm as well?